# Calling System.Linq.Enumerable.Any throws exception on Windows 10

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq, window

I have got a windows desktop application which uses EF4 (I know it is old) as ORM to connect to database and I am experiencing a weird issue on Windows 10 when I call "Any" for one of the object types in database. The following is the exception:

**Exception Info:**

> System.TypeInitializationException Stack:    at
>   System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].GetResults(System.Nullable`1)
>   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()
>   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalQuery`1[[System.__Canon,
>   mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].GetEnumerator()    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TResult>.GetEnumerator()
>   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Any[[System.__Canon, mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1)
>   at
>   Bootstrapper.LoginModel.HasUserAcceptedTraining(Int32)

I have tried the exact same application on different Windows and also on another Windows 10 machines and it is not happening. I have tried the following:

1. Checked the database and it was fine
2. Checked the .NET version and compared it with Windows 10 machine the application works fine on it and it was the same (Target version 4.0.0, Version 4.6.0079, Release 393295)
3. Tried fusion log to see whether there is any problem in loading any assembly
4. Re-installed the application - no change

I don't know what else I can do to find the issue? Has anyone experience such an issue on windows 10? Any thought on that?

**Update** :
I have added exception handling to the application and now this is the exception I am getting after running the application:

[2015-09-08 13:21:07.8404] [Error   ] - Exception Occurred in Method MainForm_Load - Details : The type initializer for 'ProxyTypeBuilder' threw an exception.,    at System.Data.Objects.Internal.EntityProxyFactory.ProxyTypeBuilder.MarkAsNotSerializable(FieldBuilder field)
   at System.Data.Objects.Internal.EntityProxyFactory.ProxyTypeBuilder.RegisterInstanceField(FieldBuilder field, Boolean serializable)
   at System.Data.Objects.Internal.LazyLoadImplementor.Implement(TypeBuilder typeBuilder, Action`2 registerField)
   at System.Data.Objects.Internal.EntityProxyFactory.ProxyTypeBuilder.get_TypeBuilder()
   at System.Data.Objects.Internal.EntityProxyFactory.ProxyTypeBuilder.CreateType(ModuleBuilder moduleBuilder)
   at System.Data.Objects.Internal.EntityProxyFactory.BuildType(ModuleBuilder moduleBuilder, ClrEntityType ospaceEntityType)
   at System.Data.Objects.Internal.EntityProxyFactory.TryCreateProxyType(EntityType ospaceEntityType)
   at System.Data.Objects.Internal.EntityProxyFactory.GetProxyType(ClrEntityType ospaceEntityType)
   at System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Translator.Visit(EntityColumnMap columnMap, TranslatorArg arg)
   at System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.EntityColumnMap.Accept[TResultType,TArgType](ColumnMapVisitorWithResults`2 visitor, TArgType arg)
   at System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Translator.ProcessCollectionColumnMap(CollectionColumnMap columnMap, TranslatorArg arg, ColumnMap discriminatorColumnMap, Object discriminatorValue)
   at System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Translator.Visit(SimpleCollectionColumnMap columnMap, TranslatorArg arg)
   at System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.SimpleCollectionColumnMap.Accept[TResultType,TArgType](ColumnMapVisitorWithResults`2 visitor, TArgType arg)
   at System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Translator.TranslateColumnMap[TRequestedType](QueryCacheManager queryCacheManager, ColumnMap columnMap, MetadataWorkspace workspace, SpanIndex spanIndex, MergeOption mergeOption, Boolean valueLayer)
   at System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.ShaperFactory.TypedShaperFactoryCreator`1.TypedCreate(QueryCacheManager cacheManager, ColumnMap columnMap, MetadataWorkspace metadata, SpanIndex spanInfo, MergeOption mergeOption, Boolean valueLayer)
   at System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.ShaperFactory.Create(Type elementType, QueryCacheManager cacheManager, ColumnMap columnMap, MetadataWorkspace metadata, SpanIndex spanInfo, MergeOption mergeOption, Boolean valueLayer)
   at System.Data.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlan.Prepare(ObjectContext context, DbQueryCommandTree tree, Type elementType, MergeOption mergeOption, Span span, ReadOnlyCollection`1 compiledQueryParameters, AliasGenerator aliasGenerator)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ELinqQueryState.GetExecutionPlan(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalQuery`1.GetEnumerator()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TResult>.GetEnumerator()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Any[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at HasUserAcceptedTraining(Int32 userID)

Comment: `System.TypeInitializationException` - this is 99.99% a problem of missing some dll, the Type in that dll cannot be initialized (once you used it) because the dll is missing. You should double check on that direction. Maybe some dll is supposed to be already installed on other versions of Windows but has been removed in Windows 10.

Comment: As far as I remember if an assembly is missing fusion log reports it to you. I have enabled fusionlog and it didn't report any missing assembly. In addition to that the same installer works on other Windows 10 installation (with the same version and .NET version number).

Comment: What database is this? MSSQL or something else?

Comment: @Poseidon is there anything wrong with the logging mechanism? you totally trust in it? from my experience, that kind of exception means some Type cannot initialize successfully, nothing wrong with the linq query.

Comment: `System.__Canon` - this is what you should search for, it may relate to  some JIT engine to inject something at runtime, ... it's fairly complicated to me. That means it may work in other versions of Windows but fails in Windows 10.

Comment: @Hopeless : It is the output of the Windows event viewer. System.__Canon is the type used in reflection as far as I know.

Comment: @LukeMcGregor It is SQL database and I use EF4 as ORM to connect to SQL Server 2008.

Comment: @Poseidon so do you see this exact exception (you posted) in windows event viewer? you assume it should say clearly that *some dll is missing*? I don't think it's smart like that. What you got is just the exception or if you program your own app/library, you can log to Windows Event system your own message (in this case of course it's not - I mean the mscorlib.dll). Anyway `TypeInitializationException` is what you should fix, searching it around to see when it is raised may also help.

Comment: @Hopeless I didn't exactly get what you mean. What I did was I have added some more logging + exception handling and updated the issue description. Log now shows that "ProxyTypeBuilder" cannot be initialised. I don't know why it is different from what was written in event viewer!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90195/discussion-between-poseidon-and-hopeless).

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't fix the issue so what I did was re-installed the windows and now it works fine!